# Change range in string during loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I need to query 5000 rows of data, but cannot query the whole 5000. How can I incorporate a loop to change the ranges of this url? The url needs to be modified during each loop to look like `1:1000`, `1001:2000`, `2001:3000`, `3001:4000`, `4001:5000`.

How can I use a loop and format the string for these ranges?

```
url = 'https://data.epa.gov/efservice/PUB_DIM_FACILITY/ROWS/1:1000/JSON'
test = pd.read_json(url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop to modify the range, and then use an `f-string` for the url:

```
for i in range(5):
    start = 1+1000*i
    end = 1000*(i+1)
    url = f"https://data.epa.gov/efservice/PUB_DIM_FACILITY/ROWS/{start}:{end}/JSON"
    test = pd.read_json(url)
```